# Android save multiple switch states in recycler adaper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have list of dynamically added permissions with switch views. Inside onBindViewHolder I am using setOnCheckedChangeListener to update checked state of each switch separately, but when I leave the adapter, switch states are all reset to not checked.

Here is my onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public PermisssionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    //Inflate view
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(RjioSettingsApplication.get()).inflate(R.layout.permission_info_layout, parent, false);
    final PermisssionViewHolder holder = new PermisssionViewHolder(view);

    holder.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onItemClicked(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                if (holder.getPermissisonSwitch().isChecked()) {
                    holder.getPermissisonSwitch().setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    holder.getPermissisonSwitch().setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PermisssionViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    final PermisssionItem permission = items.get(position);

    //Permission switch view
    holder.getPermissisonSwitch().setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.getPermissisonSwitch().setChecked(items.get(position).isPermissionChecked());
    holder.getPermissisonSwitch().setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                items.get(position).setPermissionChecked(true);
            } else {
                items.get(position).setPermissionChecked(false);
            }

            System.out.println("################## IS CHECKED " + isChecked);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    //Permission title
    holder.getTitle().setText(permission.getPermission());
}
```

Comment: Hey @alezniki What do you mean but when I leave the adapter,

Comment: No need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `onCheckedChanged` callback. Also, where do you define the `clickListener` in the `onCreateViewHolder `?

Comment: I mean when I leave the screen with listed permissions, and then when i come back switch views are all unchecked

Comment: And also, where do you define the `items` in `onBindViewHolder `...?

Comment: Click listener is defined in custom base adapter which u exend from

Comment: Items are list of permission items, it is also extended from BaseAdapter as protected List<K> items = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable **boolean** in your data list model.

```
     private boolean isChecked;

     public boolean isChecked() {
            return isChecked;
        }
     public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            isChecked = checked;
        }
```

Then check item in **RecyclerView** as

```
VHitem.checkIndividual.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, checked) -> {
                        if (!onBind) {
                            selectIndividualCheckBox(checked, holder.getAdapterPosition());
                        }
                    });

private void selectIndividualCheckBox(boolean isChecked, int position) {
            Model model = model.get(position);
            model.setChecked(isChecked);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: It is still same output, it remembers the current state but as soon as I leave that screen and go back switch views are all unchecked.

Comment: Save your model in Shared preference... Load your data from saved shared preference value.

Comment: Thanks Na Ran, the problem was that because of dynamically added permissions shared preferences needs unique key for each one.

Comment: that depends on how you edit shared preference.. anyway.   Good to know you solved the issue..